# MS Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit Generate Strong Types for Entities remember list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I've installed **Microsoft Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit** to connect to my Dynamics CRM instance. I'm then using the toolkit to generate my strong types as a single class called `Entities.cs` - I decided to do this by selecting a sub-set of Entities rather than the full set to try and reduce the size of my plugin. This has worked well and I've started producing my plugins.

The issue is that I missed an entity to include in my strong types in `Entities.cs`. So I've reopened the developer toolkit and right clicked on Entities to generate the class but it hasn't saved the list of entities that I had selected previously.

For my team, this can be a potential problem as there are a lot of people working on this, and if they do not select the correct entities they could introduce errors.

Is there a way of saving the list of selected Entities to be generated?

[image: Strong Types]

Answer (score 1):

I see this as a major issue as well.  I've sent an e-mail to the MS team, you may want to create a review on the VS Gallery Extensions website as well.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DynamicsCRMPG.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMDeveloperToolkit

In the mean time, I'd recommend to use either the CrmSvcUtil, or the EarlyBoundGenerator plugin for the XrmToolBox.

Comment: Thanks @Daryl, I've done both, posted a review and reverted back to the older toolset. A shame because this tool looks like it would be quite useful once they get the bugs out